# Use multiple rows from the same table in UPDATE of one row in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.1

I am using pgadmin for PostgreSQL (9.1) and I have this query which takes too long to run

```
update tableA a
set owner1_surname = (select owner_surname from owners_distinct b where a.owner1= b.owner),
owner1_othername   = (select owner_othername from owners_distinct b where a.owner1= b.owner),
owner2_surname     = (select owner_surname from owners_distinct b where a.owner2= b.owner),
owner2_othername   = (select owner_othername from owners_distinct b where a.owner2= b.owner),
owner3_surname     = (select owner_surname from owners_distinct b where a.owner3= b.owner),
owner3_othername   = (select owner_othername from owners_distinct b where a.owner3= b.owner)
```

Instead of having to retrieve the values from `owners_distinct table` again and again, is it possible to retrieve the columns `owner`, `owner_surname` and `owner_othername` just once using `SELECT` and then do `UPDATE` on `tableA`'s columns based on the check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trickier than I first thought, since you want to join the same table multiple times, and the only connection is the updated table itself:

```
UPDATE table_a a
    SET owner1_surname = b1.owner_surname
    ,owner1_othername  = b1.owner_othername
    ,owner2_surname    = b2.owner_surname
    ,owner2_othername  = b2.owner_othername
    ,owner3_surname    = b3.owner_surname
    ,owner3_othername  = b3.owner_othername
FROM   table_a x
LEFT   JOIN owners_distinct b1 ON b1.b.owner = x.owner1
LEFT   JOIN owners_distinct b2 ON b2.b.owner = x.owner2 
LEFT   JOIN owners_distinct b2 ON b3.b.owner = x.owner3
WHERE  x.table_a_id = a.table_a_id
```

Where `table_a_id` is the primary key of `table_a`. Normally you don't have to join the table another time, but in this situation you need it for the join *before* you can link to the updated table.

I use `LEFT JOIN`, in order to prevent the whole update for a row from failing if one of the three owners cannot be found in `owners_distinct`.

#### Database design

Are you sure you need all the **redundant data** in `table_a`? The canonical way in a normalized schema would be to only store the  `foreign keys` (`owner1`, `owner2`, `owner3`), and fetch details of the name on demand with a `JOIN` in a `SELECT`. Remove all those columns you are updating altogether. Of course, there are always exceptions to the rule ...

#### No unique key?

This shouldn't happen to begin with. You should add a surrogate primary key like:

```
ALTER TABLE table_a ADD table_a_id serial PRIMARY KEY;
```

More about that in the related answer:
[Do I need a primary key for my table, which has a UNIQUE (composite 4-columns), one of which can be NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516661/do-i-need-a-primary-key-for-my-table-which-has-a-unique-composite-4-columns/10518219#10518219)

#### Solution without unique key

Anyway, here is a way to make this update regardless of *any* unique column:

```
UPDATE table_a a
    SET owner1_surname = b1.owner_surname
    ,owner1_othername  = b1.owner_othername
    ,owner2_surname    = b2.owner_surname
    ,owner2_othername  = b2.owner_othername
    ,owner3_surname    = b3.owner_surname
    ,owner3_othername  = b3.owner_othername
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT owner1, owner2, owner3 FROM table_a) x
LEFT   JOIN owners_distinct b1 ON b1.b.owner = x.owner1
LEFT   JOIN owners_distinct b2 ON b2.b.owner = x.owner2 
LEFT   JOIN owners_distinct b2 ON b3.b.owner = x.owner3
WHERE  x.owner1 = a.owner1
AND    x.owner2 = a.owner2
AND    x.owner3 = a.owner3;
```

The point is: we only need each combination of `(owner1, owner2, owner3)` once.

Comment: @CCGooner: *Every* table should have a primary key. This one doesn't? Either way, any unique combination of columns can do the job. The whole row if need be. Just avoid columns that can be `NULL`.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT owner, owner_surname and owner_othername FROM table_a

UPDATE table_a a

```
 SET owner1_surname = b1.owner_surname
,owner1_othername  = b1.owner_othername
,owner2_surname    = b2.owner_surname
,owner2_othername  = b2.owner_othername
,owner3_surname    = b3.owner_surname
,owner3_othername  = b3.owner_othername
```

Comment: I want owner1_surname, owner1_othername to be updated only if table_a.owner1=owners_distinct.owner and same for owner2surname, owner2othername and owner3surname, owner3othername

Comment: before this code try to put in this condition:

IF table_a.owner1=owners_distinct.owner and same for owner2surname, owner2othername and owner3surname, owner3othername